# C#. Запрос к SOAP WEB службе

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

Здравствуйте. Необходимо подключится к web службе по протоколу SOAP.
Клиент написан на C# WPF.
Mex точки доступа на службе НЕТ, поэтому сгенерировать прокси клиента через WCF не выйдет.
В тех задании указан запрос-ответ к службе в XML формате.

ЗАПРОС

```
<?xmlversion="1.0" encoding=" utf-8" ?>
  <root>
    <AuthenticationUser=’ddd’ Password=’samba’/>
     <PlaceESR=’34567’/>
  </root>
```

ОТВЕТ

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
<Place ESR=’34567’ Data=’2015.09.21’/>
<Train TrainNumber=’6022’ Name=’Москва-Ожерелье’ ESRDeparture=’34567’ ESRArrival=’34560’ TimeDeparture=’2015.09.21 11:11:00’ TimeArrival=’’DaysTrainType=’ОН’ DaysTrain= ‘2015.09.15;2015.09.17;2015.09.22’>
    <PlacesStop>
        <Place ESR=’23451’ />
        <Place ESR=’23457’ />
    </PlacesStop>
    <PlacesNotStop>
    </PlacesNotStop>
</Train>
<Train TrainNumber=’6021’ Name=’Ожерелье-МОсква’ ESRDeparture=’34560’ ESRArrival=’ 34567’ TimeDeparture=’’ TimeArrival=’2015.09.21 12:05:00’ DaysTrainType=’Ежедневно’ DaysTrain= ‘’>
    <PlacesStop>
    </PlacesStop>
<PlacesNotStop>
    </PlacesNotStop>
</Train>
</root>
```

Подскажите с чего начать создавать клиента для опроса сервиса? Как отлаживать обмен информацией? Есть ли в интернете открытые сервисы для отладки?

Заранее всем спасибо!!!

Comment: Данный сервис не открыт, он находится в локальной сети. Поэтому хотелось бы подготовится до подключения к нему на месте.

Comment: У вас запрос и ответ - не SOAP.

Comment: ХМм. я с SOAP дело не имел, но в Тех. зад. написано так. "Информационный обмен между АПК-ДК (СТДМ) и системой информирования пассажиров (далее просто клиент)предлагается осуществлять посредством выполнения запросов к SOAPWEBслужбе АПК-ДК (СТДМ) (далее просто сервер).   Для  нормативного расписания  интерфейс WEB сервера GetScheduleNormative4Place. Данные запроса представляют собой xml документ, имеющий следующий формат:"  и формат я привел.